# Chaining thunks that return promises don't chain as expected

Tags: javascript, redux, es6-promise, redux-thunk

I have a series of async actions that I want to chain:

```
const update = (obj) => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      dispatch(updateTriggers(obj))
      resolve()
    })
  }
}

const arrayifyTriggers = () => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      const obj = getState().Dashboard.triggersObj
      const arr = Object.values(obj)
      resolve(arr)
    })
  }
}

export function updateTriggers (trigger) {
  return {
    type: UPDATE_TRIGGERS,
    payload: trigger
  }
}
```

I expected to chain them like this:

```
export const handleChange = (obj) => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch(update(obj))
    .then(dispatch(arrayifyTriggers()))
    .then(arr => dispatch(receiveTriggers(arr)))
    .catch(err)
  }
}
```

But that doesn't work; here's what does work:

```
export const handleChange = (obj) => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch(update(obj))
    .then(dispatch(arrayifyTriggers())
      .then(arr => dispatch(receiveTriggers(arr)))
     )
  }
}
```

So my question is twofold. Why doesn't it work the way I expect and have I done something incorrectly?

In general, using thunks and Promises together are pretty tough to get my head around, so even some specific thoughts about best practices for using these together would be appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: "In general, using thunks and Promises together are pretty tough to get my head around"

<-- Sorry, if I'm being annoying and I know that this doesn't answer your question, but have you considered using redux-saga instead of redux-thunk?

Comment: Not annoying at all! Thanks for pointing it out. It set me on a long path of reading and learning. That said, I don't think generators will be part of the future of async. I think they are too obtuse. My prediction is that async-await will be adopted more enthusiastically (at least within a redux like context).